# Factor analysis with different experimental conditions: Implications(?)

Tags: pca, repeated-measures, experiment-design, factor-analysis, assumptions

I have conducted (exploratory) factor analysis (EFA) on data from a within-subject design **with four different experimental conditions**. Each participant goes through all conditions one after the other (in a random order, of course), within a 1-hour session.

I have scoured Cross Validated and read a lot of posts about PCA with repeated measures, but I believe this case is different because it is not simply about repeated measures but about the implications of adding to that **different experimental conditions**.

#### Question

What are the implications for conducting EFA on collapsed repeated-measures data *from different experimental conditions* (e.g., which assumes that each observation is independent/comes from a different person—though we know this is not true)? Is this a valid approach? What are the possible limitations or caveats?

**Note:** I am not interested in suggestions of alternative methods (SEM, multilevel EFA/CFA, etc.), just to more fully understand the limitations and implications of the current method.

Comment: It is simple. Imagine you have two (or more) within-subject exp. conditions, that is, a repeated-measures factor. If the factor has its effect (the conditions differ) but you treat each within-subject observation as an individual, independent subject, you are at risk to get spurious correlations which are due to location and/or slope heterogeneity of such "boosted" sample of individuals. E.g., Simpson's paradox. "Distorted" correlations will produce distorted factors.

Comment: Thank you @ttnphns, this is very useful, especially the pointing of Simpson's paradox. I will here leave a reference to a good paper in this regard for future reference:

Kievit, R., Frankenhuis, W., Waldorp, L., & Borsboom, D. (2013). Simpson's paradox in psychological science: A practical guide. Frontiers in Psychology, 4(513). https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00513